# Suppose $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a(n) < \infty$, what about $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty a( \frac{n}{\log(n)})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n= 0}^\infty a(n) < \infty$, can we say something about the convergence of $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty a( \frac{n}{\log(n)})$ ?

- Assume that $a(n)$ is monotonically decreasing and non-negative.
- I think if $a(n)$ can be bounded by a geometric series then the second series also converges, but this is as if we would assume more then summability for $a(n)$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're assuming that $a(x)$ is non negative, right?

Comment: Right, thanks !

Comment: So is $a$ an $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ function? Also you better start the second sum from $n=2$. $n/\log n$ does not make sense for $n=0,1$.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $a: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ is monotonically decreasing. Then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {a\!\left( {\frac{n}{{\log n}}} \right)} \;\text{ converges }\Longleftrightarrow \int_e^{ + \infty } {a\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log x}}} \right)\mathrm{d}x} \;\text{ converges. }
$$
Now due to the monotonicity of $a$, we have
$$
\int_e^{ + \infty } {a\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log x}}} \right)\mathrm{d}x}  = \int_{e}^{ + \infty } {a\!\left( {\frac{{t\log t}}{{\log (t\log t)}}} \right)(\log t + 1)\,\mathrm{d}t}  \ge \int_{e}^{ + \infty } {a(t)\log t\,\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\int_e^{ + \infty } {a\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log x}}} \right)\mathrm{d}x} & = 2\int_{1.98 \ldots }^{ + \infty } {a\!\left( {\frac{{2t\log t}}{{\log (2t\log t)}}} \right)(\log t + 1)\,\mathrm{d}t} \\ &  \le 2\int_{1.98 \ldots }^{ + \infty } {a(t)(\log t + 1)\,\mathrm{d}t}  \le 6\int_{1.98 \ldots }^{ + \infty } {a(t)\log t\,\mathrm{d}t} .
\end{align*}
Thus, if $a \cdot \log$ is also monotonically decreasing, then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {a\!\left( {\frac{n}{{\log n}}} \right)} \;\text{ converges }\Longleftrightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  a(n)\log n \;\text{ converges. }
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was roughly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 5):

The convergence of $\sum_{n=10}^\infty f(n)$ does not imply the convergence of $\sum_{n=10}^\infty f\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$. Indeed, taking $f(n)=\frac{1}{n\log^2n}$, we have $\sum_{n=10}^\infty f(n)$ converges. On the other hand,
$$
\sum_{n=10}^\infty f\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)=\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac{\log n}{n\left(\log n-\log\log n\right)^2}\approx\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log n}
$$

The last sum is divergent by the integral test.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting this. Are there reasonable conditions that ensure that $a(\frac{n}{\log n})$ is summable, without assuming more than summability for $a(n)$?

Comment: @ARedder: I'm not sure I understand. You *have* to assume more than just summability of $a(n)$ to ensure $a(n/\log n)$ is also summable. One possible assumption is $a(n)=O\left(\big(n (\log n)^3\big)^{-1}\right)$, though this is stronger than necessary.

Comment: @Clayton Yes that's clear. I was just wondering if one could get away with summability + something else. But I guess something else always boils down to assuming more than summability.